# A ternary number consists of only 2 s, 1 s and 0 s. How many values can be represented by a 7 digit ternary number?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand that this question is a permutation and combination question so my method of calculating the answer was:

There are 7 possible digits however we can only choose 1's,2's,or 0's

So I did    $7!/3!$

But i'm pretty sure this incorrect can someone please help me :)

Comment: How many one digit numbers can be so expressed?  Surely it isn't $\frac {1!}{3!}$.   Once you've done one digit numbers, do two digit numbers until you see the pattern.  Note:  you should clarify the question though.  Is, say, $0000001$ allowed?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Reduce the number of digits to smaller number first. How many base 10 numbers are there?
2. Before going back to 7 digit numbers, how many base 3 numbers are there?
3. Solve the original problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant that there are 7 digits in the number: but as for the base 3 numbers would it just be 3^3

Comment: @Priit, the point of my hints is to use intuition with base 10 numbers. Would the answer be $7!/10!$ in that case?

Comment: Oh wait, for the 3 digit number would it be 18

Comment: @Ennar That's not an integer, so no.

Comment: how is 18 not an integer?????

Comment: @Priit, that depends whether you allow leading $0$'s or not. Usually, we don't allow them, but in computer science you might want to allow leading $0$'s if you interpret digits as memory.

Comment: nah this isnt compsci its just maths

Comment: @Priit You see how your name wasn't at the start of the comment? That means it's not a reply to you.

Comment: @Priit, then it seems to me that you have it figured out :)

Comment: Ah sorry :) I dont really use these forums, But i think i  have it figured out!  the answer to the original question would be 2 * 3^6